# REGEX within querydsl

Tags: java, postgresql, java-8, querydsl

I have the following code:

```
return property.value.eq(value)
                .or(property.value.startsWith(value + ","))
                .or(property.value.endsWith("," + value))
                .or(property.value.like("%," + value + ",%"));
```

What it does is pretty self-explanatory, it looks for the following scenarios `...,value`, `value,...`, `...,value,...`, `value`.

Is there a way to use REGEX within a query using *QueryDSL* in order to simplify this expression to one line?

Comment: Are you using QueryDSL SQL or JPA? Because in particular JPA's query language is very limited w.r.t. regular expression matching.

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling This is using QueryDSL SQL